# Can't find source of style

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, styles

I got a problem, when coming to designing my site.
If anyone can find out, what adds the white colour between the lines in the drop-down menu, i would very much appreciate it! Because no style on the page, gives that white border, and i just want to get rid of it!

http://www.ny-webdesign.dk/bio7

This is the link, so if anyone can find the source to the colour, I would very much appreciate it!

```
   <a> <li> <ul>
```

Those are the tags I think contains the border, but I am not sure!

This is the link, so if anyone can find the source to the colour, I would very much appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the below it disappears.

```
ul.sub-menu{
  border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: ps: this is for the 1px border of the dropdown, not the thicker underlines, as i guess those are there for purpose

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry, but i tried to provide a solution for the question. As there are two different kind of white borders on the actual item, i provided my solution for one, and then realised that he may had requested for the other one, so i commented on my own answer (haven't seen the edit option on the answer, as you can see I'm a newbie here). I didn't criticised nor added anything malevolent, just tried to help...

Comment: @Rico this provides an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's in `#header #navigation ul.nav > li.parent:hover a:before`. If I set it to `content: none;`, there appears no border.